# emu 8086 password verfication

Tags: assembly, user-input, emu8086

I want to make a program that asks the user to input a password and ask for confirmation. It shall then save the entered value to the bx register and put 3 in cx for loop.

Then the program will ask the user again for the just created password. If the user enters the correct password, the program shall print the password.

However, currently the program just exits after the password is verified and does not print it. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
msg db 10,13, 'please insert a new password$'
msg1 db 10,13, 'confirm the password$'
msg2 db 10,13,'password is not the same whith first one ,re enter it!$'
msg3 db 10,13,'password is verfied$'
p1 dw ?
p2 dw ?
a db 10
b db 100


m1 db 10,13,'this program is created by firoo , for use of password verfication:$'
m2 db 10,13,'please input the correct password to proced:$'
m3 db 10,13,'invalid password$'
m4 db 10,13,'the password is  correct congra!$'
p dw ?
count dw 3
.code
main proc 
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov dx,offset msg
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
mul b
mov p1,ax

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
mul a
add p1,ax

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
add p1,ax
mov bx,p1
add bx ,30h
mov p,bx

l1:mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
mul b
mov p2,ax

mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
mul a
add p2,ax
mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub ax,30h
add p2,ax
mov bx,p2
add bx,30h

cmp bx,p
jne notv
mov dx,offset msg3
mov ah,09h
int 21h
jmp l2
notv:
mov dx,offset msg2
mov ah,09h
int 21h
jmp over


l2:mov cx,count
mov bx,[p]

mov dx,offset m1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov dx,offset m2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

again: mov ah,08
int 21h

cmp al,[bx]
jne error
inc bx
loop again

mov dx,offset m4
mov ah,09h
int 21h

jmp over
error:mov dx,offset m3
mov ah,09h
int 21h
over:mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I have proposed an edit to your question in an attempt to clarify and structure the question. Please check my edit to see whether I have worded your question correctly!

Comment: ... also, it would help if you could add some comments to your code to make it easier for others to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the program just exits after the password is verified and does not print it.

**a.** "Does not print it"

That's because there's no code in the program that actually prints the password!

**b.** "just exits after the password is verified"

Due to calculation inaccuracies, your program might think passwords are different where the inputs were identical!

> ```
> mov ah,01h
> int 21h
> sub ax,30h
> add p1,ax
> ```

When you ask for a character, DOS will return it in `AL`. You consistently use `AX`. In those cases where a subsequent multiplication occurs this error goes by silently, **but** for the input of the 3rd character this error can show itself since DOS (implementations) could potentially return garbage in `AH`.

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h     <<<< AL
mul b
mov p1, ax

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h    <<<< AL
mul a
add p1, ax

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h    <<<< AL
cbw            <<<< This clears AH
add p1, ax

mov bx, p1
add bx, 30h    <<<< Why do you add this ?
```

At this point in the code `BX` contains a number from 0 to 999. Adding 30h to it makes no sense!

Make the same corrections for the inputs of the confirming password.

---

> ```
> notv:
> mov dx,offset msg2
> mov ah,09h
> int 21h
> jmp over       <<<< ???
> ```

If the (confirming) password is not the same as the first one, you tell the user to re-enter it, **but** then you jump to the exit of the program! For re-entering you need to jump to the *l1* label instead.

---

> ```
> again: mov ah,08
> int 21h
> cmp al,[bx]
> jne error
> inc bx
> loop again
> ```

The code that runs when passwords should match will nearly always jump to *error* because you compare the result of a single **character** input with the low byte of your password **number** in the range 0-999. Remember at `[bx]` there's just a binary value and certainly not a text string.

> ```
> mov bx,[p]
> ```

This brings the contents of the password in `BX`. Therefore it makes no sense to use `BX` for addressing purposes like in `cmp al, [bx]`.

Comment: Please excuse me  if you have a time the way to contact whith you for better assembley language understanding,  if you have a time your email or something to contact whith you?